# When using the assigned color are green, black, brown for pH, EC, SOC but obtaining results are black, green and brown respectively . Why?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using ggplot2 the assigned color is different from the plot map. Assigned color of pH, EC, SOC are green, black, brown but obtaining ploting map the pH, EC, and SOC are black, green and brown respectively. Why?

I am trying to plot these maps with defined colors but color of obtaining maps are not exactly matched with assined.

Comment: Hi, for people on StackOverflow to help you better, please include the a code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and the `ggplot2` code that you used to create this plot. The code is important for us to see where the issue may arise.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.